# How can I read a packet with on my nginx server, I am sending the packages with packet sender

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, iot

I am sending TCP packets with packet sender. I need to process those packets on my Nginx web server.

I am going to store the data on my database and present it on the front-end later on with MeteorJS. Can I do the packet receiving with node.js and how?

I'll be appreciated if you can help me, thanks.

Comment: of course you can, but the how depends on how you would like it. Since your packets are HTTP not just TCP, I would recommend using a server-side router to your meteor project and accept GET or POST requests there, depending on what your sender sends. More details would require you being more specific.

Comment: There is an electronic board that is collecting information from sensors, it is going to be sending those packages to my server IP through some port I guess. I am trying to simulate that with packet sender software. The server needs to receive those packets, open them, and put that data to the database while also presenting them to the front-end side.

Comment: First you need to find out whether that board will be using TCP or HTTP (on top of TCP). Depending on that you'll need to read about opening TCP sockets or create HTTP server routes in JS. Whatever you find should go directly into your meteor project server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled this situation with node.js using createServer from "net", here is my server main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createServer } from "net";

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const server = createServer(socket => {
    socket.write("RECEIVED!")
    socket.on("data", data => {
      const text = data.toString();
      console.log(text);
    })
  })

  server.listen(8080)

});
```